# Excel Conditional formatting on two criteria in a separate table

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

This is a reporting presentation exercise...

**I am looking for the magic to change the colour of the cell without changing the contents of the cell.**

I have a type of crosstab table, which has the ROWS individual CustomerIDs, and the COLs as months.

**PRESENTATION TABLE**

| CustomerID | Jan 22 | Feb 22 | Mar 22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | $100 | $50 | $10000 |
| 0002 | $1000 | $1000 | $200 |
| .... | .... | ... |  |

And in a separate table, I have some data which I want to use in a conditional formatting type of way.

**LOOKUP TABLE**

| CustomerID | Period | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Feb 22 | Applied |
| 0001 | Mar 22 | Pending |
| 0006 | Mar 22 | Approved |
| 0009 | Dec 23 | Pending |

Let's say that if the CustomerID and Period in the data table has the label "Applied" then I want that cell in the top table, where CustomerID and Period intersect, to be coloured RED. If it's "Passed", I want it to be coloured green, and so on.

The periods are dates data types. The tables are excel tables.

The dollar value in the cell has nothing to do with it.

I've seen some techniques where a combination of Named ranges and confditional formatting are used, but I'm stumped.

I can put the dollar values in the correct cell by putting a helper column into my source data (the second table) and then doing an xlookup on the combination of the row and col headers, against that helper column.

But then I run out of steam.

**END RESULT**

| CustomerID | Jan 22 | Feb 22 | Mar 22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 |  | RED | BLUE |
| 0002 |  |  |  |
| .... | .... | ... |  |

Comment: A simple COUNTIFS should do what you want.  What have you tried?  Can you show your attempt to do this?

Comment: You may try any one of the functions `COUNTIFS()` or `SUMPRODUCT()` to accomplish the output.

Comment: Why Count? or Sum? I'm trying to colour the cell based on the label.... I'm confused.

Comment: The reason behind to use those functions because it gives the count of the following matches which you are setting as a criteria, it will give you either `1 ` or `0` and if its `1` then the intersection shall be highlighted

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, please correct me if am wrong. May be my explanation is not good, if you can please make OP provide a proper explanation. sorry for my **English**

Comment: O...k....   So countif the value occurs in the data table, and format accordingly?

Comment: Yeah absolutely !

Comment: Yeah, but then I can't have the dollars showing. I want the magic to change the colour of the cell without changing the contents of the cell.

Comment: Why should the contents of the cell change?

Comment: Sorry my bad. You're talking about the conditional formtting formula, not the formula in the cell.... right?

Comment: @Maxcot Sir, yes I am talking about conditional formatting only since the title of your query seemed to me like that

Comment: OK, so I can count that it occurs. But what value is it? The lookup on that row and col is more than 1. But is it "Applied" or is it "Pending" or what?

Comment: @Maxcot Sir, check I have shared one solution, may be you are looking for that only,

Comment: Thanks, but no, your solution doesn;t solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Conditional Formatting On Two Criteria In A Separate Table

*This* is what I have tried,

[image: CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING]

• Formula used in Conditional Formatting for **Applied**

```
=COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$5,$A2,$G$2:$G$5,B$1,$H$2:$H$5,"Applied")=1
```

Special credit to **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir for the above formula

• And for the **Pending** you may try using `SUMPRODUCT()` or `COUNTIFS()` Function as well, both way it works,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A2=$F$2:$F$5)*(B$1=$G$2:$G$5)*($H$2:$H$5="Pending"))=1
```

Comment: Thanks Mayukh. Your example worked nicely. I actually changed it a bit by putting your long formula into a Named Range, and then using the named range in the Conditional formatting. Makes it a bit simpler, because that Conditional formatting logic is so weird (for me anyway)

Comment: @Maxcot Sir, glad to know that sir, that you have worked it out, thank you for sharing the feedback. !